# Auto increment a primary key column

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, auto-generate

I have a page bank transfer that contains a column "transfer Number" in my asp.net application. This is an auto generated column. I am taking this value based based on the query:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tableName) = 0
    SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('tableName')
ELSE
    SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('tableName') + 1
```

The problem is when two user login, it shows same transfer number for this page. How can I show different Transfer number for different users before inserting a record?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

set the column as identity and the values will be generated automatically, and after insert, you can get the inserted id from the  variable @@identity. Like this

Table Design

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable
(
SeqNo INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
Col1 VARCHAR(50),
Col2 INT,
...
)
```

I have set the column SeqNo as Identity and Primary key.

Identity(1,1) means the first value will be 1 and then for each row the increment will be +1 and so on.

Now I insert a record to the table

```
INSERT INTO YourTable(Col1,Col2)
values('abc',1)

select @@identity
```

Now after the insert, the 2nd select will return me the value 1 as the value of the identity field is 1.

If I run this one more time, I will get 2 and so on

You can also call the System defined function SCOPE_IDENTITY() (in case triggers are involved) instead on @@IDENTITY

You can avoid conflicts using this since the values are generated by the database itself

Comment: Better to use SCOPE_IDENTITY() instead of @@IDENTITY in case there are triggers involved.